# How to Get 'Recipient' Names and emails address from Outlook using Python MAPI

Tags: python, outlook, automation

Just like `.SenderName` gives me names of the Senders which can be easily appended to a list, is their any object to do the same for the 'Recipients' of my mails.

I have tried `.Recipients` but once added to the list they appear as `COMObjects` which cannot be manipulated by Python.

All I want is a simple list of Recipient names.

Comment: Can you post your current code so we can look at it?

Comment: Sorry, organization code.

Comment: Okay so you are trying to get the senders email address?

Comment: Yes, email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The simplest way to do that is*

*Example*

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders["0m3r@Email.com"].Folders["Inbox"]


def get_email_address():
    for message in inbox.Items:
        print("========")
        print("Subj: " + message.Subject)
        print("Email Type: ", message.SenderEmailType)
        if message.Class == 43:
            try:
                if message.SenderEmailType == "SMTP":
                    print("Name: ", message.SenderName)
                    print("Email Address: ", message.SenderEmailAddress)
                    print("Date: ", message.ReceivedTime)
                elif message.SenderEmailType == "EX":
                    print("Name: ", message.SenderName)
                    print("Email Address: ", message.Sender.GetExchangeUser(
                                                              ).PrimarySmtpAddress)
                    print("Date: ", message.ReceivedTime)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                continue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_email_address()
```

Comment: Where have you actually parsed the recipient address? I don't see it anywhere

Comment: I’m running loop on inbox emails @Gahan

Comment: that I see but I see that you are only getting sender email not recipient email, so basically information parsed is from `From:` you missed recipients email which are from `To:` or `Cc:` or `Bcc:`

Answer (score 1):

The [MailItem.Recipients](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868965(v=office.15).aspx) property returns a `Recipients` collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item. In VBA, for example, you can use the following:

```
Dim recip As Recipient
Dim allRecips As String

For Each recip In item.Recipients
    If (Len(allRecips) > 0) Then allRecips = allRecips & "; "
    allRecips = allRecips & recip.Address
Next
```

The Outlook object model is common for all kinds of programming languages and applications. So, you can use the same property and method calls to retrieve the same results.

The [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863703(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Recipient class returns or sets an integer representing the type of recipient. For the MailItem the value can be one of the following [OlMailRecipientType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865653.aspx) constants: olBCC, olCC, olOriginator, or olTo.

Also the Recipient class provides the following properties:

- [Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868965(v=office.15).aspx) - a string value that represents the display name for the recipient.
- [Address](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867602(v=office.15).aspx) - a string representing the e-mail address of the Recipient.
- [AddressEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863677(v=office.15).aspx) - the [AddressEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869306.aspx) object corresponding to the recipient.

Comment: Hello, Thank You for the answer. As You mentioned that .Recipients return a collection, which was causing issues for us, we used instead `.To` which returned values that could be easily handled with Python(or any other language).

Comment: You can try to use the `To`, `Cc`, `Bcc` properties.

Comment: Yah, exactly, did that. `.To`

Answer (score 1):

The `.Address` property only returns email addresses for non-Exchange accounts. For Exchange accounts, it returns that weird string. To extract email addresses only for both Exchange and non-exchange accounts:

```
for x in message.Recipients:
     try:
         print(x.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress)
     except AttributeError:
         print(x.AddressEntry.Address)
```