# Get emails from non-default PST using MAPI

Tags: python, outlook

I am using MAPI in python to get the emails from specific folder of PST. But, if I have multiple PSTs then how to get emails from folder of different PST file. Currently I am able to get the emails from default folder only.

Thank you.

I am using following code, I can access the folders of default PST, how to change the PST.

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")                                    
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["Test Folder"]
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the relevant snippets of your code that you are trying to improve.

Comment: Added. Thanks..

Comment: use email address, example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62802619/4539709

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All stores in a given profile (including PSTs) can be accessed through the `Application.Session.Stores`. You can also use `Application.Session.Folders` collection (returns top-level folders from all stores in the given profile).

For example, if your PST store is named "My PST", and you want to access "Test Folder" child folder under the Inbox in that store, use

```
inbox = outlook.Stores["My PST"].GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders["Test Folder"]
```

Comment: Could you mention the code as per code mentioned in the question. Thanks.

Comment: See the updated answer above answer above.

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. Thanks again.